# cakephp: fail to make a pagination because of using 'group'

Tags: cakephp

i want to make a pagination via using 'group':

```
var $paginate = array(
        'Student'=>array(
                    'limit' => 20,
                    'fields'=>array('Student.id','Student.firstname','Student.lastname'),
                    'order' =>array('Student.id'=>'desc'),
                    //'group' => array('Student.type_id'),
                ),
        );
```

when i commmentted the line " 'group' => array('Student.type_id') ",  the pagination will work well, but when i unlock this line,  i only can get 20 items (same as limit number) from database, and no pagination.

so , how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Update to CakePHP 2.3 (currently beta) and it's been fixed.  Anything before that, you have to create a few custom functions [detailed in the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html).